Python ChromaDB Error - Unable to compute the prediction using a neural network model
I'm running this code attempting to add some data to a ChromaDB collection.
import ollama, chromadb, time

chroma_client = chromadb.Client()
#chroma_client = chromadb.HttpClient(host="localhost", port=8000)

collectionname = "my_collection"

print(chroma_client.list_collections())
if any(collection.name == collectionname for collection in chroma_client.list_collections()):
    print("deleting collection")
    chroma_client.delete_collection("my_collection")

collection = chroma_client.get_or_create_collection(name=collectionname, metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine"})

collection.upsert(
    documents=[
        "This is a document about machine learning",
        "This is another document about data science",
        "A third document about artificial intelligence"
    ],
    metadatas=[
        {"source": "test1"},
        {"source": "test2"},
        {"source": "test3"}
    ],
    ids=[
        "id1",
        "id2",
        "id3"
    ]
)

But I'm receiving this error message bac.  and I'm not sure where to go at this point to resovle. Has anyone seen it before and have a resolution?
2024-07-13 17:31:45.534848 [E:onnxruntime:, sequential_executor.cc:516 ExecuteKernel] Non-zero status code returned while running CoreML_16713284627214834184_1 node. Name:'CoreMLExecutionProvider_CoreML_16713284627214834184_1_1' Status Message: Error executing model: Unable to compute the prediction using a neural network model. It can be an invalid input data or broken/unsupported model (error code: -1).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joe/development/python/gettings_started_chromadb.py", line 15, in <module>
    collection.upsert(
  File "/Users/joe/development/python/venv/dev/lib/python3.11/site-packages/chromadb/api/models/Collection.py", line 296, in upsert
    ) = self._validate_and_prepare_upsert_request(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joe/development/python/venv/dev/lib/python3.11/site-packages/chromadb/api/models/CollectionCommon.py", line 531, in _validate_and_prepare_upsert_request
    embeddings = self._embed(input=documents)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joe/development/python/venv/dev/lib/python3.11/site-packages/chromadb/api/models/CollectionCommon.py", line 568, in _embed
    return self._embedding_function(input=input)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joe/development/python/venv/dev/lib/python3.11/site-packages/chromadb/api/types.py", line 211, in __call__
    result = call(self, input)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joe/development/python/venv/dev/lib/python3.11/site-packages/chromadb/utils/embedding_functions/onnx_mini_lm_l6_v2.py", line 200, in __call__
    return cast(Embeddings, self._forward(input).tolist())
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joe/development/python/venv/dev/lib/python3.11/site-packages/chromadb/utils/embedding_functions/onnx_mini_lm_l6_v2.py", line 143, in _forward
    model_output = self.model.run(None, onnx_input)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joe/development/python/venv/dev/lib/python3.11/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 220, in run
    return self._sess.run(output_names, input_feed, run_options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.Fail: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Non-zero status code returned while running CoreML_16713284627214834184_1 node. Name:'CoreMLExecutionProvider_CoreML_16713284627214834184_1_1' Status Message: Error executing model: Unable to compute the prediction using a neural network model. It can be an invalid input data or broken/unsupported model (error code: -1).

I initially thought I may have a corrupted Python environment so I cleaned up all packages and created a virtual environment that only has Python 3.11, Ollama, ChromaDB, and Time installed.  I also thought it may be a local issue with Chroma so I build a Docker image as well and deployed but still received the same error.

This is an issue when running in Mac with Intel chips. You can solve this by taking these steps:
Change the onnxruntime version:
!pip install onnxruntime==1.16.3

and install sentence_transformers:
!pip install sentence_transformers

Now, you create the embedding separately:
from chromadb.utils import embedding_functions
sentence_transformer_ef = embedding_functions.SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

and then loop through your documents and upsert separately:

documents = ["This is document1", "This is document2"]
metadatas = [{"source": "notion"}, {"source": "google-docs"}]
ids = ["doc1", "doc2"]

for doc, meta, id in zip(documents, metadatas, ids):
    collection.upsert(
        documents=[doc],
        embeddings=[sentence_transformer_ef(doc)[0]],
        metadatas=[meta],
        ids=[id],
    )

This will work.

THIS should be the accepted answer.  I am using an iMac with Intel Chip and this works wonderfully!

@GeekyGeek's response is correct and it works.
however, I just wanted to share that I found another solution from this ChromaDB Github page.   I tested out the suggestion and it works like a charm - you can KEEP your collections.add() statement.
However, you're still required  to install onnxruntime but no  need to specify the onnxruntime version and it should work (I use the latest Nov 2024 version).
pip install onnxruntime

Here is the updated code - I tested it with your collection.add() statement and it works:
# add this import statement 
from chromadb.utils.embedding_functions.onnx_mini_lm_l6_v2 import ONNXMiniLM_L6_V2

# create an embedded function variable 
ef = ONNXMiniLM_L6_V2(preferred_providers=["CPUExecutionProvider"])

# finally, modiy your `get_or_create_collection` statement by passing the embedding_function parameter
collection = client.get_or_create_collection(collectionname, metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine"}, embedding_function=ef)

# now you can run your collection_add() statement successfully
collection.add(
    documents=[
        "This is a document about machine learning",
        "This is another document about data science",
        "A third document about artificial intelligence"
    ],
    metadatas=[
        {"source": "test1"},
        {"source": "test2"},
        {"source": "test3"}
    ],
    ids=[
        "id1",
        "id2",
        "id3"
    ]
)

